# How to play H.264 video in browser?

Tags: html, video-streaming, h.264

I have transcoded each frame of my video from RGB -> YUV12 -> H264. On the exit I have H.264 video stream and I want to watch it without VLC media player and etc.

Stream should be available from different devices such as PC, tablet, smartphone in this way

I will use only browser.

> Which method to choose?

Maybe Flash helps? Transcode video from h.264 to mp4? Anything else?

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<video>` tag supports RTSP streams.
On Firefox, Chrome and IE9+, you can use:

```
<video src="rtp://domain.com/stream">
    Your browser does not support RTP streams.
</video>
```

or

```
<video src="rtsp://domain.com/stream">
    Your browser does not support RTP streams.
</video>
```

In good old IE8, VLC comes with an ActiveX plugin (VLC web-plugin) that allows video streaming:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
     codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
     width="640" height="480" id="vlc" events="True">
   <param name="Src" value="rtsp://cameraipaddress" />
   <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
   <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
   <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
   <embed id="vlcEmb"  type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="640" height="480"
     target="rtsp://cameraipaddress" ></embed>
</OBJECT>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Firefox on Ubuntu does not seem to display a valid RTSP stream that VLC happily displays. What is needed to display RTSP streams in the browser?